# React application uptime monitoring

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, monitoring, amazon-cloudfront

How do you monitor the uptime of a react application deployed onto AWS Cloudfront/S3? More specifically the home page has rendered? It should also be able to handle any redirects. Are there any free/open source tools out there? I havn't had any luck finding any.

Something that can hit the DNS and check that a component exists on the home page? I was thinking of writing a custom script in AWS Lambda which runs every so often that can do this, but are there any examples that I could follow?

Comment: Hi, I'm also having the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: not yet unfortunately